# ActionScript Drag and Drop Display Objects With Mask And Filter?

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, filter, mask

i've created a sprite to drag and drop around the stage.  the sprite is masked and has it's mask as it's child so that it too will drag along with the sprite.  everything works fine until i add a drop shadow filter to the sprite.  when the drop shadow is added, i can only mousedown to drag and mouseup to drop the sprite if the mouse events occur within the original location of the sprite when it was added to the stage.

how can i fix this problem?  could this be an issue with 10.1?  if not what am i doing wrong?

```
var thumbMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
thumbMask.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
thumbMask.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 75, 25, 25);
thumbMask.graphics.endFill();

var thumb:Sprite = new Sprite();
thumb.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
thumb.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 75);
thumb.graphics.endFill();

thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

thumb.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20, 1.0, 3)];

thumb.addChild(thumbMask);
thumb.mask = thumbMask;
addChild(thumb)

function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    evt.target.startDrag();
    trace("drag");
    }

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    evt.target.stopDrag();
    trace("drop");
    }
```

**----------------
UPDATED SOLUTION
----------------**

thanks to the binary's suggestion, the issue is solved by using cacheAsBitmap.  however, when i applied cacheAsBitmap to the container, which was housing the masked thumb sprite that has already a drop shadow applied, the mouse events were not working as well as expected.  after reading the docs, i learned that adding a filter to a sprite automatically activates the cacheAsBitmap property for that sprite:

> The cacheAsBitmap property is
>   automatically set to true whenever you
>   apply a filter to a display object
>   (when its filter array is not empty),
>   and if a display object has a filter
>   applied to it, cacheAsBitmap is
>   reported as true for that display
>   object, even if you set the property
>   to false. If you clear all filters for
>   a display object, the cacheAsBitmap
>   setting changes to what it was last
>   set to. [1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap)

so i believe the error was caused by having 2 cacheAsBitmap properties within the same container sprite.  therefore, in this situation, i've simply added the filter to the container rather than to the masked thumb sprite.

```
var thumbMask:Sprite = new Sprite();
thumbMask.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);
thumbMask.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 75, 25, 25);
thumbMask.graphics.endFill();

var thumb:Sprite = new Sprite();
thumb.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
thumb.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 75);
thumb.graphics.endFill();

thumb.addChild(thumbMask);
thumb.mask = thumbMask;

var container: Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(thumb);
container.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20, 1.0, 3)];

//if there is no filters applied or if the filters array is empty, use:
//container.cacheAsBitmap = true;

addChild(container);

container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    evt.target.startDrag();
    trace("drag");
    }

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    evt.target.stopDrag();
    trace("--DROP");
    }
```

Comment: while this remains an unsolved mystery, i've managed to hack a solution together.  what i did was remove the drop shadow from the draggable masked sprite.  i created a sprite of the same size and placed it below the draggable masked sprite on the display list.  i've added the drop shadow to this new layer instead of the masked sprite.  the new drop shadow layer follows the masked sprite by adding and removing the Event.ENTER_FRAME for each MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP respectively.  this enter frame event calls a new function that aligns the masked sprite and the new drop shadow sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can work around this too by wrapping your `thumb` clip into a container.
set `cacheAsBitmap` to `true` and adjust the event-handling.

```
    thumb.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(0, 0, 0, 1, 20, 20, 1.0, 3)];

//  thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
//  thumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

var cont: Sprite = new Sprite();
    cont.addChild(thumb);
    cont.cacheAsBitmap = true;
    cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    cont.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

    addChild(cont);
```

so maybe you'll don't have to deal with a second sprite for your dropshadow.
hope this helps..
regards..

Comment: ok i got it to work.  thanks.  i've updated the working code using your suggestion.  it's a far better solution than my hack.

Comment: oh, i just discovered a problem.  it seems that not all of the contained sprite is calling the mouse down event.  namely, the lower and right portions of the masked rect.

Comment: ah, i got it.  the problem was the drop shadow.

from the documentation:  "The cacheAsBitmap property is automatically set to true whenever you apply a filter to a display object (when its filter array is not empty), and if a display object has a filter applied to it, cacheAsBitmap is reported as true for that display object, even if you set the property to false. If you clear all filters for a display object, the cacheAsBitmap setting changes to what it was last set to."

i've updated my code to show the working solution and to include this explination.